# Building Android instrumented tests

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I've been following the [android testing codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) and trying to model my app in a similar manner. Doing so hasn't panned out all that well. When I try to run/build my android tests I get errors when using support library classes such as AppCompatActivity and TextInputLayout. The error says:

```
The type android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout cannot be found in source files, imported jack libs or the classpath
```

I ran `./gradlew app:dependencies` and indeed these are not found in the classpath:

```
androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1 -> 25.3.1
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
+--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
|    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
|    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2
|    +--- com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:2.0
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2 (*)
\--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2
     \--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2 (*)
```

My build.gradle files has the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    ...
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2"
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1"
}
configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
    println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
        configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
    }
}
```

Note the `configurations.all` and the `configurations.compile` taken directly from the codelab. I tried adding the support libraries as `androidTestCompile` dependencies, but it seems to do nothing. When I remove the `configurations.compile` block I can see the support library in the dependency tree for `androidTestCompile` but the build itself still fails with the same error.

Unfortunately I can't release the entire code. Has anyone run into something like this? Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, everything works great during regular debug and release builds. Only when running the androidTest builds do I see this error.

**UPDATE 2:**

The issue appears to be around the jack build toolchain. I'm still not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Do you declare `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` in the `dependencies` block?

Comment: Yup, I'll update to include these. The app builds and runs 100%. So I also have access to com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.

This issue is specific to using the *jack* toolchain and the *Support Repository/Google Repository v46*. When using version 45 of the Google Repository everything works great, but version 46 breaks the build for instrumented tests. I suppose this won't matter once AS 2.4 comes out with official support for Java 1.8.